# Updating table from temp table with many rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a main table called repos, and a temp table from a csv, that I want to match the name, and update a value with the new value from the temp table. My code works, but is slow.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(name text, language text);
COPY tmp FROM 'path/to/csv';

UPDATE repos
    SET language = x.language
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tmp) x
WHERE repos.name = x.name
```

Comment: Switch to an actual table, i.e. not a temp table, any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the subquery is unnecessary.  It doesn't affect performance but it is awkward:

```
UPDATE repos
    SET language = x.language
FROM tmp x
WHERE repos.name = x.name;
```

For this query, you want an index on `tmp(name, language)`:

```
create index idx_tmp_name_language on tmp(name, language);
```

Creating an index is usually faster after the table has been populated (as opposed to creating the index first and then loading the table).